# Error in starting spyder (for python). How to fix it?

Tags: python, spyder, pythonxy

I installed python(x,y) and spyder IDE comes buit-in with that. I installed python(x,y) home 2.7.5.2 for Windows 7 x64. However when I select spyder with debug option, I get following error:

```
Usage: spyder [options] files

spyder: error: no such option: --debug
```

What this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: You mean spyder the IDE?

Comment: Probably there is no such option `--debug`, that's why you see this. Also, I think the default way of passing options on Windows is with `/`

Comment: Yes, spyder IDE. How to start spyder then? I am a beginner and don't have much idea.

Comment: Did you try `spyder` without any options?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Yes, please try to start Spyder without any option and report back to see if that works.